# Best way to apply design pattern for a given Database design in C# Classes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have designed database structure for a medium size project in MS.NET, I need to design the C# classes by using design patterns(All 3 Types). How I can find the best matching pattern for the Project. Any easiest way to find the matching patterns?

Comment: You can't really just decide oh lets do this design pattern or this one.. You have a problem and you read about it and then you find "Ah, this pattern will work for it...". But a good place to start is [here](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns)

Comment: Thanks for the Comments

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite subjective.

You may use the `Repository` pattern that will add a wrapper over your database layer.

You will probably need an `MVC` pattern to separate the views and business logic.

Apart from that, you may also use the `Factory` pattern to simplify the creation of objects and probably use the Singleton pattern to apply to the `Factory`